# Which one of the following functions dominates the other one?

Tags: functions, exponential-function, special-functions

Which of the following function dominates the other one?

1) $f(x)= \log(x+1)$  and   $g(x)= x$ as functions from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$.

2) $f(x)=2^x$  and $g(x)=1000000x$ as functions from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Is this a multi-part problem?  See this [introduction to posting mathematical expressions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  In what setting did you find these problems?

Answer (score 1):

**PLEASE USE THIS HINT**:  Consider two functions $f(x), g(x)$. The function $f(x)$ is said to dominate over $g(x)$ if $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} = 0$$ A simple application of this hint easily gives us the required answers. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes but I have to demonstrate it without using limits or derivatives

Comment: @Dr.Draaak:  then you should say that in the question.  As the limit is the definition of one function dominating another, I don't know why it should not be allowed.  What *is* allowed?